# Windows 10 upgrade via tricking Windows 8.1 Enterprise Edition to think that it is Professional Edition?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10

I have Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 bit on a VM, and I want to free upgrade to Windows 10. ( I don't want to install everything from new )

According to [this answer the free upgrade is not provided by Microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/947725/upgrade-windows-8-1-enterprise-to-windows-10)

However [according to this answer it is possible](https://superuser.com/questions/479292/downgrading-windows-8-from-enterprise-to-pro) to 'trick' Windows 8 to change its edition from Enterprise to Professional, after which an upgrade to Windows 10 Professional should be allowed.

Are there any potential issues in getting around the upgrade restrictions in this manner?

Comment: Have you managed to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Enterprise users are not entitled to the free upgrade. A potential issue to using this 'trick' is that it is piracy.