# How do I upgrade from Windows 8.1 Enterprise to Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Related question: [Upgrade Windows 8.1 Enterprise to Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/947725/upgrade-windows-8-1-enterprise-to-windows-10) References the evaluation and answer recommends a managed upgrade.

I have a Visual Studio Professional with MSDN subscription.  This gives me access to the Enterprise edition of Windows 10 (and Windows 8.1).  I currently have Windows 8.1 installed on a home PC.  I would like to **upgrade** to Windows 10, without having to wipe my drive and/or do a clean install.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn798755.aspx?ocid=wc-tn-eval#administration has instructions for doing an in-place upgrade of Enterprise edition via System Center, but because this is a home PC it isn't managed via System Center so that option doesn't work for me.

The instructions here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise appear to be specifically for the evaluation, not for a full single-machine upgrade.  Also it says:

> We do not recommend that you install this evaluation if you are not an IT professional or are not professionally managing corporate networks or devices.

---

Note: I don't mind moving to Windows 10 Pro if that is an easier option as I don't actually leverage any of the Enterprise features.

Comment: download the Win10 Enterprise ISO, mount it, run setup.exe from the mounted iso drive and select "Upgrade"

Comment: Create an answer with this and I'll accept it.  I did this and it worked, though running setup didn't prompt for "Upgrade" if I remember correctly.  None the less, the general steps did work (download ISO from MSDN, mount (double click), run setup.exe and follow instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to MSDN, login with your account and download the Windows 10 Enterprise ISO. Now make a double click on the ISO to mount it. Now run the `setup.exe` from the mounted ISO/DVD. Now follow the instructions to upgrade your Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm looking through the FAQ for "supported operating system upgrades" [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/faq), but I cannot find it, but I do, however, remember it being Windows 7 and above.*

So, I was going to mention that you simply download the [Windows 10 media creation toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), which allows you to apply the Windows 10 update directly to your system or create a USB/DVD, but the website mentions this:

---

> If you’re on an Enterprise edition, the media creation tool won’t work
>   for an upgrade. Please see the [Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx) for
>   more information.

So, there you go.